# Regular expression to separate smileys from text

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I am trying to create a regular expression in Javascript to separate any occurrence of `:)` from the surrounding text.

Given the following:

> :)This is a line of text :) with several smileys in it :). So there.,:):)

I would like to get the resulting 8 groups:

1. :)
2. This is a line of text
3. :)
4. with several smileys in it
5. :)
6. . So there.,
7. :)
8. :)

At the moment I use `([^:)]+)` which only groups the surrounding text without the smileys. What adjustment could I make so that the smileys are also grouped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split strings but preserve delimiters in the array of splits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854736/split-strings-but-preserve-delimiters-in-the-array-of-splits)

Answer (score 2):

split:

```
var string = "Given the following: :)This is a line of text :) with several smileys in it :). So there.,:):)";
var groups = string.split(/:\)/);
```

This will return an array in which each element is a part of text without `:)`.

Since the text has been split on each `:)`, we can construct the result you want by adding a `:)` between each parts of text:

```
var parts = [groups[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < groups.length; ++i) {
    parts.push(':)');
    parts.push(groups[i]);
}
```

The result is this:

1. :)
2. This is a line of text
3. :)
4. with several smileys in it
5. :)
6. . So there.,
7. :)
8. :)

**Try this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gxr6U/3/**

---

If you want to replace smilies by images, you could do this:

```
var frags = document.createDocumentFragment();

frags.appendChild(document.createTextNode(groups[0]));

for (var i = 1; i < groups.length; ++i) {

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src='http://../smiley.png';

    frags.push(img);

    frags.appendChild(document.createTextNode(groups[i]));
}
```

---

If you just want to remove smilies:

```
var text = groups.join('');
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var str = ":)This is a line of text :) with several smileys in it :). So there.,:):)",
    matches = str.split(/(\:\))/);
console.log(matches);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9saaN/).

Added filtering to remove the empty matches from the above:

```
var str = ":)This is a line of text :) with several smileys in it :). So there.,:):)",
    matches = str.split(/(\:\))/),
    matched = [];
for (var i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (matches[i].length) {
        matched.push(matches[i]);
    }
}
console.log(matched);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9saaN/1/).

A further version, with actual on-screen output:

```
var str = ":)This is a line of text :) with several smileys in it :). So there.,:):)",
    matches = str.split(/(\:\))/),
    matched = [], li,
    list = document.createElement('ol');
document.body.appendChild(list);
for (var i = 0, len = matches.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (matches[i].length) {
        matched.push(matches[i]);
        li = document.createElement('li');
        txt = document.createTextNode(matches[i]);
        li.appendChild(txt);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
console.log(matched);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9saaN/2/).

Comment: Matching the split delimiter is [not a standard behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split): “If *separator* is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. However, not all browsers support this capability.”

Answer (score 0):

The following will successfully group the string you mentioned as you want:

```
your_match = your_string.match(/(:\)|[^:)]*)/g)
```

However, like your original RegExp, you will encounter problems if a `:` or `)` appears without being in a smiley.  These characters will disappear from the match groups if not within a smiley.

Comment: What about something where `:` is not followed by `)` or `)` is not preceded by `:` like `):):`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I ended up going with 
([^:\)]+)|(:\))

Comment: Hmm on second thoughts...It messes up when I put either a ':' or ')'

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
/:\)|(?:[^:]+|:(?!\)))+/g
```

This matches either `:)` or any character except `:` or a `:` that is not followed a `)`.