# regexp split and keep the seperator

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking at tonnes of questions, documents and tutorials on regexp and how to split and keep the delimiter and still don't know how to do it...

This the string I have...

```
<span class="code special">&lt;html&gt;</span>
```

and I want to split it into this one...

```
"<span class="code special">", "&lt;html&gt;", "</span>"
```

So I was trying to split it on the less than and greater signs... but it works, but keeps removing the split characters...

I have this one at the moment...

```
'<span class="code special">&lt;html&gt;</span>'.split(/[<>]/);
```

Comment: Which side of the split do you want the split characters to go?

Comment: on the left side so I want to keep the html characters together and the html tags together...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, because the strategy in [the other question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12001989/578288) won't work here. It tells you how to split before the `<`, but not after the `>`. I was writing up an answer when this was closed. Here's the code I produced: [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/fPvYy/). In order to split *after* the `>`, I used a `replace` step to add a globally unique marker after each `>`, and then split on that marker in the `split` step. This way is kind of hacky, and it would be better to use multiple `split`s, but this works.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane wow.... this work... you sir are my savior!...