# Split and keep deliminator, preferably with regex

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have this text:

```
1.1 This is the 2,1 first 1.2 This is the 2,2 second 1.3 This is the 2,3 third
```

and I want:

```
["1.1 This is the 2,1 first","1.2 This is the 2,2 second","1.3 This is the 2,3 third"]
```

Note that:

- I  can't use `re.findall`, since I can't think of a way to properly terminate the match. The best I could think of was `'[0-9]+\.[0-9]+^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)*'`, which didn't work.
- I can't just store the delimiter as a global variable, since it changes with each match.
- I could not use a regular `re.split` because I want to keep the delimiter. I can't use a lookbehind because it has to be fixed width, and this isn't.

I have read [regexp split and keep the seperator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323764/regexp-split-and-keep-the-seperator), [Python split() without removing the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866128/python-split-without-removing-the-delimiter), and [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators), and still don't have an answer.

Comment: But you *don't* keep the delimiter (the space) on which you're splitting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can:

```
\b\d+\.\d+
.+?(?=\d+\.\d+|$)
```

See it [**working on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ABNxgQ/1). To be used in addition to `re.findall()`:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'\b\d+\.\d+.+?(?=\d+\.\d+|$)')
string = "1.1 This is the 2,1 first 1.2 This is the 2,2 second 1.3 This is the 2,3 third "
matches = rx.findall(string)
print(matches)
# ['1.1 This is the 2,1 first ', '1.2 This is the 2,2 second ', '1.3 This is the 2,3 third ']
```

If the string spans across multiple lines, use either the **dotall mode** or `[\s\S]*?`.
See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/HXe4Tb).

Answer (score 0):

split with blank whose right is 1.2 2.2 ...

```
re.split(r' (?=\d.\d)',s)
```