# Split a string of HTML into an array by particular tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this HTML as a string "html", how can I split it into an array where each header `<h` marks the start of an element?

**Begin with this:**

```
<h1>A</h1>
<h2>B</h2>
<p>Foobar</p>
<h3>C</h3>
```

**Result**:

```
["<h1>A</h1>", "<h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p>", "<h3>C</h3>"]
```

**What I've tried:**

I wanted to use `Array.split()` with a regex, but the result splits each `<h` into its own element. I need to figure out how to capture from the start of one `<h` until the next `<h`. Then include the first one but exclude the second one.

```
var html = '<h1>A</h1><h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p><h3>C</h3>';
var foo = html.split(/(<h)/);
```

**Edit**: Regex is not a requirement in anyway, it's just the only solution that I thought would work for generally splitting HTML strings in this way.

Comment: Why would you want to use regex for that?

Comment: If there's a way not to use regex, I'm totally willing to use that instead :)

Comment: You use a language hosted in the most advanced HTML parser on the planet, not using those HTML parsing capabilities is kinda silly.

Comment: Can you explain what should be the input and output?

Comment: @Tomalak - sorry which HTML parsing abilities are you referring to?

Comment: I'm talking about a web browser. Also, where does that HTML string come from? Is it by any chance already part of the markup from the page this script runs in?

Comment: It is not. It's being translated from markdown first, then I want to split it into an array because I end up doing some other work before it get's rendered. If it was in browser, I'd just traverse with jQuery's `.nextUntil()`

Comment: What other work, please explain. (This is an XY problem, i.e. you've decided on a solution already and don't bother explaining the task anymore. Please explain the task itself, not the anticipated solution.)

Comment: Add it to an invisible/hidden div, do whatever is needed with JS and DOM traversal, move the div in to the right place and set it to visible.

Comment: use html parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @kishan There is a HTML parser right in the browser, there is no need at all for an external library.

Comment: Ok, I'm taking dynamic markdown that I'm scraping from GitHub.  Then I want to render it to HTML, but wrap every title element in a ReactJS `<WayPoint>` component.  The most efficient way I can think of to do this is get the markdown, translate it to HTML string, split it, then map over it wrap it with the container.  But that is a super specific question, and the generalizable question that I couldn't find an answer to is "split a string with inclusion and exclusion in javascript". But I think the answer is just regex, unless you see something else.

Comment: @DonnyP Check out `document.createDocumentFragment()`

Comment: That's super interesting - had no idea that or anything related to it (shadow DOM?) existed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your example you can use:

```
/
  <h   // Match literal <h
  (.)  // Match any character and save in a group
  >    // Match literal <
  .*?  // Match any character zero or more times, non greedy
  <\/h // Match literal </h
  \1   // Match what previous grouped in (.)
  >    // Match literal >
/g
```

```
var str = '<h1>A</h1><h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p><h3>C</h3>'
str.match(/<h(.)>.*?<\/h\1>/g); // ["<h1>A</h1>", "<h2>B</h2>", "<h3>C</h3>"]
```

But please don't parse HTML with regexp, read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: That is an amazing SO question / answer.

Comment: Downvote for advocating regex to an HTML problem. At your reputation, you should know better than that.

Comment: Tomalak, come on, he's giving me a good answer and being helpful. I understand that in general regex shouldn't be used to parse HTML. But this is a good answer in this situation.

Comment: No, not "in general". Never. Especially not when you have an incredible HTML parser and DOM API and tons of libraries to deal with HTML and DOM right at your fingertips. Especially then it's the worst possible approach.

Comment: His answer is 1 line. If I put this in my code with a comment above saying "split on headers", it's really easily readable.  If the powerful HTML and DOM libraries can make the code better, then I'm all for it

Comment: @DonnyP This is not code golf. "Doing it in one line" is not the goal of it. His answer is inappropriate to the problem. HTML cannot be dealt with using regular expressions. This will crash and burn, just wait and see when you try it out on real life code.

Comment: @DonnyP I think Tomalak's main point is code stability not readability.

Comment: Ah, how does it improve stability? Is the idea here that HTML is just too variable to be safely handled by regex? (Which I agree with) I understand someone doing any real processing on anything that wasn't super structued by a markdown parser would end up in trouble. Just curious if I'm missing something else.

Comment: @DonnyP I think you got it! I show you that it is possible with your example data, but I also warns you that you should reconsider your approach, especially if you don't know what data you are dealing with. Feel free to try to see if it works on all your data sets. If it does, then great! But if it don't it's simply because you are trying to start a fire with water :-)

Comment: @DonnyP HTML is not "too variable". HTML is in a category of languages (non-regular) that regular expressions inherently cannot describe. This is a hard technical limitation of regular expressions. Trying to do it anyway means one of two things: Either you limit yourself to a strict sub-set of HTML that can be described as a regular language (you're not doing that, you take unknown code off of GitHub), or you have a nasty one-liner bug sitting in your code. I wonder if "But it's only one line!" is a good enough reason for the latter.

Comment: @Tomalak what is your opinion of: 1. Parsing code/markdown with regex? For instance https://github.com/developit/snarkdown and https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/? 2. Parse the output-HTML from a markdown parser with Regex?

Comment: @user1506145 1) The core argument is this: Regex can deal with complex patterns. Regex cannot deal with *indefinitely nested* complex patterns. Markdown does not have many ways of creating indefinite nesting, but it's possible. For example, off the top of my head, this is markdown ``This is [a [[link]]](http://to/a/url?with(parentherses))`.` - but if your regex did not plan for 3 levels of bracket nesting then it will break. Yes, some regex dialects can count brackets. The one in built into JS can't. And bracket counting is not enough in more complex situations.

Comment: @user1506145 This means a regex-based markdown parser is always a compromise, it covers not what's possible, but what the author thought to be likely. And the more it covers, the more unmaintainable its core regex becomes. 2) For HTML, machine-generated or not, the basic rule applies - don't. I can think of at least one way to break the innocuous-looking regex in the answer above with perfectly valid input, and this regex here does not even try to do anything complex. Just don't.

Answer (score 10):

From the comments to the question, this seems to be the task:

> I'm taking dynamic markdown that I'm scraping from GitHub. Then I want to render it to HTML, but wrap every title element in a ReactJS `<WayPoint>` component.

The following is a completely library-agnostic, DOM-API based solution.

```
function waypointify(html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div"), nodes;

    // parse HTML and convert into an array (instead of NodeList)
    div.innerHTML = html;
    nodes = [].slice.call(div.childNodes);

    // add <waypoint> elements and distribute nodes by headings
    div.innerHTML = "";
    nodes.forEach(function (node) {
        if (!div.lastChild || /^h[1-6]$/i.test(node.nodeName)) {
            div.appendChild( document.createElement("waypoint") );
        }
        div.lastChild.appendChild(node);
    });

    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Doing the same in a modern library with less lines of code is absolutely possible, see it as a challenge.

This is what it produces with your sample input:

```
<waypoint><h1>A</h1></waypoint>
<waypoint><h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p></waypoint>
<waypoint><h3>C</h3></waypoint>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure someone could reduce the for loop to put the angle brackets back in but this is how I'd do it.

```
var html = '<h1>A</h1><h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p><h3>C</h3>';

//split on ><
var arr = html.split(/></g);

//split removes the >< so we need to determine where to put them back in.
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(arr[i].substring(0, 1) != '<'){
    arr[i] = '<' + arr[i];
  }

  if(arr[i].slice(-1) != '>'){
    arr[i] = arr[i] + '>';
  }
}
```

Additionally, we could actually remove the first and last bracket, do the split and then replace the angle brackets to the whole thing.

```
var html = '<h1>A</h1><h2>B</h2><p>Foobar</p><h3>C</h3>';

//remove first and last characters
html = html.substring(1, html.length-1);

//do the split on ><
var arr = html.split(/></g);

//add the brackets back in
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = '<' + arr[i] + '>';
}
```

Oh, of course this will fail with elements that have no content.

Comment: If you use a look ahead, you can actually keep the separator you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question, needed the same thing in one of my projects.
Did the following and works well for all HTML strings.

```js
let splitArray = data.split("><")
    splitArray.forEach((item, index) => {

        if (index === 0) {
            splitArray[index] = item += ">"

            return
        }

        if (index === splitArray.length - 1) {
            splitArray[index] = "<" + item

            return
        }
        
        splitArray[index] = "<" + item + ">"
    })

console.log(splitArray)
```

where data is the HTML string

Answer (score 0):

Hi I used this function to convert html String Dom in array

```
  static getArrayTagsHtmlString(str){
    let htmlSplit = str.split(">")
    let arrayElements = []
    let nodeElement =""
    htmlSplit.forEach((element)=>{  
      if (element.includes("<")) {
        nodeElement = element+">"   
       }else{
         nodeElement = element
        }
        arrayElements.push(nodeElement)
    })
    return arrayElements
  }
```

Happy code