# span is rendered as text and not element in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am making a query from an api, the api returns a result snippet like this:

```
"<span class="searchmatch">Justin</span> Drew <span class="searchmatch">Bieber</span> (/ˈbiːbər/; born March 1, 1994) is a Canadian singer and songwriter. After a talent manager discovered him through his YouTube videos"
```

when i render it in my component like this:

```
{this.props.snippet}
```

it returns a text, but I want to render it as an html element. help?

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491459/split-a-string-of-html-into-an-array-by-particular-tags

Answer (score -2):

You are most likely looking for [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

And render it like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: yourStringFromApi}} />
```

Note though that this can be quite dangerous and should be avoided if possible.