# Split string by character numeric

Tags: java, regex

I am using below program to split my string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "A1=CA2=BOA2=RA4=O";
    String data[] = test.split("[A-a]\\d{1,100}=");

    for (String str : data) {
      System.out.println("Split data:"+str);
    }      
}

//Output 
  Split data:
  Split data:C
  Split data:BO
  Split data:R
  Split data:O

//But I want output something like below :
  Split data:A1=C
  Split data:A2=BO
  Split data:A2=R
  Split data:A4=O
```

How do I split my string to get output in the above way

Comment: Maybe this could work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator

Comment: Why don't you try like this? A1=C,A2=BO,A3=R,A4=O And split by (',')

Comment: will you lhs always be 2 characters ?

Comment: @AnshulJain No. lhs not fixed. That can 2 0r more then 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the positive look-ahead assertion (`(?=)`):

```
test.split("(?=[A-Z]\\d{1,100}=)");
```

This regex will match any zero-length string that is followed by (Capital letter), followed by a number consists of [1-100] digits, followed by `=` sign.

**Output:**

```
Split data:A1=C
Split data:A2=BO
Split data:A2=R
Split data:A4=O
```

Comment: Can u explain this answer please

Comment: `=[A-Z]` is not required. right? all things works with just adding `?=` what it will do? when to add or when not to add?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Your solution is working. I need a another help. After split I got "A1=C" this type of string. Now want to extract 1 from A1, 2 from A2 etc. How I get that?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty `s = s.substring(1, s.indexOf("="));`.