# Splitting an expression into an array with multiple keys and include keys as well in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
var expression = "[AccNum]==true&&[AccNum]==[ARID]&&[AccNum]==aaaa || [ARID]!=true&&[DOB]&gt;[ARID] || [DOB]&gt;bbb&&[DOS]&gt;=[ARID]&&[DOS]&lt;[Gender]&&[66642]&lt;=cccc&&[66642] In (ddd,fff,ggg) || [FirstName] NotIn (hhh,jjj,kkk)&&[FirstName] StartsWith lll || [Gender] EndsWith mmm";
```

I need to split this expression into an array like,

```
var arr = [ "[AccNum]==true","&&", "[AccNum]==[ARID]", "&&", "[AccNum]==aaaa", "||", "[ARID]!=true", "&&", "[DOB]&gt;[ARID]", "||", "[DOB]&gt;bbb", "&&", "[DOS]&gt;=[ARID]", "&&", "[DOS]&lt;[Gender]", "&&", "[66642]&lt;=cccc", "&&", "[66642] In (ddd,fff,ggg)", "||", "[FirstName] NotIn (hhh,jjj,kkk)", "&&", "[FirstName] StartsWith lll", "||", "[Gender] EndsWith mmm" ]
```

Here keys are "&&" and "||" but I need the keys as well in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var expression = "[AccNum]==true&&[AccNum]==[ARID]&&[AccNum]==aaaa || [ARID]!=true&&[DOB]&gt;[ARID] || [DOB]&gt;bbb&&[DOS]&gt;=[ARID]&&[DOS]&lt;[Gender]&&[66642]&lt;=cccc&&[66642] In (ddd,fff,ggg) || [FirstName] NotIn (hhh,jjj,kkk)&&[FirstName] StartsWith lll || [Gender] EndsWith mmm";

var converted = expression
                .split(/(&&|\|\|)/)
                .map(item => item.trim());

console.log(converted)
```

RegEx delimiter wrapped in parentheses will push the delimiter in the array along with the items, thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12002085/3499595

Map for trimming each item, removing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var expression = "[AccNum]==true&&[AccNum]==[ARID]&&[AccNum]==aaaa || [ARID]!=true&&[DOB]&gt;[ARID] || [DOB]&gt;bbb&&[DOS]&gt;=[ARID]&&[DOS]&lt;[Gender]&&[66642]&lt;=cccc&&[66642] In (ddd,fff,ggg) || [FirstName] NotIn (hhh,jjj,kkk)&&[FirstName] StartsWith lll || [Gender] EndsWith mmm";
var splitArray = expression.split(/(&&|\|\|)/g);
```