# Split a string on new lines while keeping delimiter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like below;

```
text = "\n first \n second \n third"
```

I want to split this string on new line character and keep the delimiter (\n and \r\n). So far I tried this `text.split( /(?=\r?\n)/g )` 
The result is like below:

```
["↵ first ", "↵ second ", "↵ third"]
```

But I want this:

```
["↵", " first ↵", " second ↵", " third"]
```

What is the correct Regex for that?

Comment: If your environment supports lookbehind (=if it supports ECMAScript 2018), use `text.split(/(?<=\r?\n)/)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately it doesn't support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match any text up to an CRLF or LF or end of string:

```
text.match(/.*(?:$|\r?\n)/g).filter(Boolean)
// -> (4) ["↵", " first ↵", " second ↵", " third"]
```

The `.*(?:$|\r?\n)` pattern matches

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than newline
- `(?:$|\r?\n)` - either end of string or an optional carriage return and a newline.

JS demo:

```js
console.log("\r\n first \r\n second \r\n third".match(/.*(?:$|\r?\n)/g));
console.log("\n first \r\n second \r third".match(/.*(?:$|\r?\n)/g));
console.log("\n\n\n first \r\n second \r third".match(/.*(?:$|\r?\n)/g));
```

**For ECMAScript 2018 standard supporting JS environments**, it is as simple as using a lookbehind pattern like

```
text.split(/(?<=\r?\n)/)
```

It will split at all positions that immediately follow an optional CR + LF symbol.

Another splitting regex is `/^(?!$)/m`:

```js
console.log("\r\n first \r\n second \r\n third".split(/^(?!$)/m));
console.log("\n first \r\n second \r third".split(/^(?!$)/m));
console.log("\n\n\n first \r\n second \r third".split(/^(?!$)/m));
```

Here, the strings are split at each position after a CR or LF that are not at the end of a line.

Note you do not need a global modifier with `String#split` since it splits at all found positions by default.

Comment: sounds great :)

Comment: this ( /^(?!$)/m ) will fail if you have two consequent \n like "\n\n first \n second \n third"

Comment: @Reza No, see the third example in the last demo. Or do you mean there should be 3 separate `\n` items? Then  the first solution is the most robust.

Comment: The result of third example is  ["↵↵↵", " first 
↵", " second 
", " third"] while it should be this ["↵", "↵", "↵", " first ↵", " second ↵", " third"] like the result of pattern in ECMA 2018

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript version might not support lookbehinds.  But here is a trick we can use which avoids them:

```js
text = "\n first \n second \n third"
text = text.replace(/\n/mg, "\n\n");
terms = text.split(/\n(?!\n)/);
console.log(terms);
```

This works by replacing every newline `\n` with two of them `\n\n`, and then splitting on `\n(?!\n)`.  That is, after making this replacement, we split on `\n` which is *not* followed by another newline character.  This results in consuming the second newline during the split, while retaining the first one which we want to appear in the output.

Comment: Sounds great but it's kind of small hack. Is there any other good way?

Comment: @Reza Yes, read Wiktor's comment above, and see if you can use a lookbehind to check for a `\n` prior to the split.  If you _can't_ use lookarounds, then you'll need some alternative, such as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could match on `[^\n]*\n?` (enabling `g` flag):

```js
text = "\n\n first \n\n sth \r with \r\n second \r\n third \n forth \r";
console.log(text.match(/[^\n]*\n?/g));
```

You may need to `.pop()` the returning values because the last value always is an empty string:

```
var matches = text.match(/[^\n]*\n?/g);
matches.pop();
```

Comment: The question asks for `\n` in both title and context and not `\r\n`. I only see `\r` in the OP's regex which is probably there by accident.

Comment: @revo it would be great if your answer contain \r

Comment: this ( /(?=.)^/mg ) will fail if you have two consequent \n like "\n\n first \n second \n third"

Comment: @Reza Updated. That's the simplest right way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex:

```
/.*?(\n|$)/g
```

It will match any number of any char including `Newline` '\n or end of string.

You can access the matches as an `array` (Works like splitting but keeps the separator in the match).