# javascript: result of 'yoyoyoyo'.split('y'), expected to be ['', 'o', '', 'o', '', 'o', '', 'o'], instead saw ['', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o',]

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, split

The confusing behavior of String.split():
When the split function sees a string/character that matches the search string, it would automatically replace the string with a blank string in the returned array:

```
'aaaaa'.split('a'); // returns ['', '', '', '', '']
```

But when I put it with other letters, then magically, couple blank strings disappear:

```
'abababa'.split('a'); // returns ['', 'b', 'b', 'b', '']
```

I know that it can be used to split words using

```
'apples are great'.split(' '); // returns ['apples', 'are', 'great']
```

But what about putting an extra space in between the words?

```
'apples  are  great'.split(' '); // returns ['apples', '', 'are', '', 'great']
```

If I wanted `apples  are  great'.split(' ');` to return `['apples', '', '', 'are', '', '', 'great']`, what are options to make that happen?

Comment: The blank strings don't disappear - they are replaced by the contents that you introduced between the matched instances.

Comment: What about matching regions of non-whitespace as well as spaces:  `.match(/([^\s]+|\s)/g)`

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Your request doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Hint:  `split` is not confusing at all when you consider the invariant ∀x: `x.split('a').join('a') === x`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator

Comment: *When the split function sees a string/character that matches the search string, it would automatically replace the string with a blank string in the returned array*: **No**. It returns the characters of the original string between the previous match (or the beginning of the string) and the current match (or the end of the string). The reason why `aaaaa.split('a')` returns `[ "", "", "", "", "", "" ]` (6 strings, not 5 as you stated in your question) is because there are zero characters between each match, and therefore it returns 6 zero-length strings as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. Where you match all words and all spaces and then map through them. Using trim will return empty strings if the item was a space.

```js
const res = 'apples  are  great'.match(/\w+|\s/g).map(item=>item.trim());

console.log(res);
```

Comment: That was my first take as well, but the OP actually *wants* the empty strings in his result, not avoid them. His problem is that he wants one empty string too much.

Comment: Doesn't work, still returns the same `['apples', 'are', 'great']`

Answer (score 1):

You can refer MDN Docs for split() here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split:

> When found, separator is removed from the string and the 
>   substrings are returned in an array. If separator is not found 
>   or is omitted, the array contains one element consisting of the 
>   entire string. If separator is an empty string, str is converted 
>   to an array of characters. If separator appears at the beginning 
>   or end of the string, or both, the array begins, ends, or both 
>   begins and ends, respectively, with an empty string. Thus, if 
>   the string consists solely of one instance of separator, the 
>   array consists of two empty strings.