# Take the separator into Array when splitting

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I split a string and take the separator into the array? For example I have a string with two sentences:

```
"I am learning Javascript. The most exiting programming language."
```

I would like to have following result after splitting with `split(".")` :

```
array[0] consists of "I am learning Javascript. 
array[1] consists of "The most exiting programming language."
```

I don't want to lose the punctuation at the end of a sentence. How can I achieve that?

Update:
This is not the same issue like here:
[Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

because the br-tag is not displayed, since it is html code. The punctuation in my case should be seen explicitly.

Comment: I don't think you'll need it if you use join(".")

Comment: @jtylerm `join(".")` would not add back the final `.`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: @hereticmonkey good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of splitting the string, you can match a sequence of non dots that terminates with a dot ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qrqshe/1)):

```js
const str = "I am learning Javascript. The most exiting programming language."

const result = str.match(/[^.]+\./g)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use match instead and look for any character followed by a dot an whitespace.

```js
var string = "I am learning Javascript. The most exiting programming language.";

console.log(string.match(/.*?\.\s*/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to achieve what you seek.

```
 let sentence = "I am learning Javascript. The most exiting programming language."

const splitedArray = sentence.split(".");

let i=0;

for(i;i<splitedArray.length-1;i++){
 console.log(`array[${i}] consists of `+splitedArray[i]+`.`); 
}
```

This will work for all such sentences ending with the dot(.).
This is a quick dynamic solution to your problem.
Hope this helps.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pgyovp?editors=1112