# How to split a string based on either spaces or symbols while maintaining the delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a string based on either spaces or certain symbols (presently `*_-<>`). I'll give some examples of input and output:

```
"Hello how are you" -> [ "Hello", " ", "how", " ", "are", " ", "you" ]

"Hello *how* are *you*" -> [ "Hello", " ", "*how*", " ", "are", " ", "*you*" ]

"Hello *how*are_you_" -> [ "Hello", " ", "*how*", "are", "_you_" ]

"*how*are _you_ \*doing*_today_ hm?" -> [ "*how*", "are", " ", "_you_", " ", "\*doing*", "_today_", " ", "hm?"
```

Splitting on space unfortunately turns cases like `*how*_are_` into a single item in the array instead of multiple items.

I also tried using a Regex to split on, but unfortunately it doesn't maintain the symbols surrounding each word.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing. Is there a good way to handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: Do you mean `"*how*are _you_ \\*doing*_today_ hm?"`, with a real, literal backslash?

Comment: Yeah the literal backslash is intentional. @HarunYilmaz I'll check out that answer and find out if my question differs. This is a new concept to me (lookaheads) so it will take some time for me to figure out whether or not it works here.

Comment: Probably, `s.match(/<[^\s*_<>-]+>|([*_-]?)[^\s*_<>-]+\1|\s+/g)` will help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow that seems to work with all my inputs. I'm going to spend the next 30 minutes studying that regex to try and understand it.

Comment: @RyanPeschel  I do not quite get it: do you need to match `>word>` and `<word<` together? I thought you wanted only `<word>` like things as a single token.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry about that, I think I messed up the original post (but your regex is probably enough to get me from 95% of the way there to 100%). Thankfully I don't think that part matters because I am going to have to do re-parse the items again anyways to conditionally turn them into React components (small Markdown subset). So even if it's more general than it needs to be the second parse should catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `split`, one option is to use `.match`: either match one of the symbols, followed by characters that aren't that symbol, followed by that symbol again, *or* match non-space, non-symbol characters:

```js
// Put the dash first, because it will be put into a character set:
const delims = '-*_<>';

// Construct a pattern like:
// ([-*_<>])(?:(?!\1).)+\1| |[^-*_<> ]+

const patternStr = String.raw
`([${delims}])(?:(?!\1).)+\1| |[^${delims} ]+`
const pattern = new RegExp(patternStr, 'g');

const doMatch = str => str.match(pattern);
console.log(doMatch("Hello how are you"));
console.log(doMatch("Hello *how*are_you_"));
console.log(doMatch("*how*are _you_ \*doing*_today_ hm?"));
```

`([-*_<>])(?:(?!\1).)+\1|[^-*_<> ]+` means:

- `([-*_<>])(?:(?!\1).)+\1` - First alternation:

  - `([-*_<>])` - Match and capture initial delimiter
  - `(?:(?!\1).)+` - Followed by any characters which are not that initial delimitier
  - `\1` - Followed by that initial delimiter again
- `\s` Second alternation: match a space
- `[^-*_<> ]+` - Third alternation: match anything which is not a delimiter or a space

Comment: Your answer looks to use pretty similar techniques to Wiktor's, except with the nice delims keyword to remove some repetition and his preserving the spaces. It also seems to work well, I just need to figure out _how_ it works now. Thanks for the explanation for how it works! Going to study this.

Comment: Yeah I'm using WiktorStribiżew's regex but I appreciate this answer anyways because it helps explain it and is close enough. It also gave me the idea to use a delimiter variable to make it more readable.

Comment: Ah, you wanted to capture the spaces - that's an easy tweak, just alternate with a space too

Answer (score 0):

Try (this is improved CertainPerformance [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952666/860099) )

```js
let split = s => s.match(/([-*_<>])(?:(?!\1).)+\1| |[^ ]+/g) 

console.log(split("Hello how are you"));
console.log(split("Hello *how* are *you*"));
console.log(split("Hello *how*are_you_"));
console.log(split("*how*are _you_ \*doing*_today_ hm?"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional material to study. Unfortunately negative lookbehind doesn't have enough browser support for me to use.

Comment: @RyanPeschel This answer use negative lookahead (not lookbehind) and works on chrome, safari and firefox