# How can I divide the following equation by regex?

Tags: javascript

This is my equation

```
5x^2 + 3x - 5 = 50
```

I have used this regex

```
/([+|-])([1-9][a-z])+|([1-9][a-z])+|([+|-])([1-9])+|([1-9])+/mg
```

but it does not give the results I want.

I want to divide my equation like this

```
array(
 5x^2 ,
 3x ,
 -5 ,
 =50
)
```

Comment: Mathematical formulas are too complex to be parsed with a regexp, you've to create a custom parser, or maybe search for an existing library.

Comment: What happened to the `+` after the first quadratic term?

Comment: If you're asking a regex for this specific equation: https://regex101.com/r/eHXLuC/1

Comment: Simiarly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, you could [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) your string by several mathematical operator symbols (for instance `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `=`). Then you get an array of terms but without the operators that were used to split the string:

```js
const string = "5x^2 + 3x - 5 = 50";
const regex = /\+|\-|\*|\/|=/g;

const result = string.split(regex);
console.info(result);
```

To retrieve the delimiter characters as well, [have a look at this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12001989/2764486) for example.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the whitespaces.
Then match optional `=` or `-` followed by what's not  `=` or `-` or `+`

**Example snippet:**

```js
var str = "5x^2 + 3x - 5 = 50";

let arr = str
      .replace(/\s+/g, '')
      .match(/[=\-]*[^+=\-]+/g);

console.log(arr);
```