# JavaScript, split string on basis number

Tags: javascript

```
const str = 'scsi15';

const words = str.split(/[0-15]*$/);
```

Code output: `Array ["scsi", ""]`,

However, this is the output I want: `Array ["scsi", "15"]`

Comment: do you have only one number?

Comment: `[0-15]` will be the same as `[015]` it's not "zero to fifteen"

Comment: Not quite. `[0-15]` means „Range 0 to 1 and the character 5”. That means, if it were `[0-25]` it would be equal to `[0125]` instead of `[025]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: @Ryuno-Ki I was talking about *this* regex. The tange from zero to one includes zero *and* one only.

Answer (score 0):

You could match by non digits or digits.

```js
const
    str = 'scsi15',
    words = str.match(/\D+|\d+/g);

console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to go via Regular Expression instead of `String.prototype.split`:

```js
const str = 'scsi15';
const re = /([a-z]*)(\d*)/;
const words = re.exec(str);
// => ['scsi15', 'scsi', '15']

console.log(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destruct regex capturing groups if the order is always the same

```js
const str = 'scsi15';
const re = /(\D*)(\d*)/;
const [_, word, num] = re.exec(str); // _, is first item. Could be just ,
console.log(word, num)
```

Comment: `const [, word, num]` also works - you can skip the first identifier and not assign it.

Comment: @VLAZ I know, but I always explicit include it so it shows it is deliberately omitted and not a typo or somcething.