# Split a string and keep the splitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, split, discord.js

I'm making a Discord Bot with Node.js and Discord.js, and I'm trying to achieve some kind of time reader, when a user sends something in this format `1h30m`, I want to manipulate some timer. I want to split that received string to `1h` and `30m` to manipulate them using the `str.endsWith('')`.

```js
let str = '1h30m';
if (!(/[^dhms0-9]/ig).test(str)) {
   console.log('RegExp Success.');
   duration = str.split(/[0-9]/);
   console.log(duration);
}
```

I made a condition that is only true when it has only numbers or any of the letter 'd', 'h', 'm' and 's' and nothing else. It detects it fine but when i split by numbers i get following array:

```
[ '', 'h', '', 'm' ]
```

and what i want to get is

```
['1h', '30m']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: could you give us some rules, for example could there be 2 digits number like `20h` or even more 3? is it possible to have like `0h30min`? is it possible to have `1min` or do we need always a zero like this `01min`?

Comment: @VLAZ educational and all, but isn't really the problem Wassim is having

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could match the parts by looking for digits followed by `h` or `m`.

```js
let str = '1h30m',
    duration = str.match(/\d+[hm]/gi);
    
console.log(duration);
```

Comment: just need the `s` and `d`

Comment: Add d and s in the brackets and that's the solution

Comment: that was the exact thing i was looking for, thanks!