# Split string at every occurrence of character, but keep character in new array

Tags: javascript

If I have a string which looks like this:

```
 let oldString = '[foo faa] [faaaa] [feee foo] [fu]';
```

How can I split it to return the following:

```
let newArr = ['[foo faa]','[faaaa]','[feee foo]','[fu]'];
```

So I would like to split it at every ']' character, but keep to that character in the new array.

I've tried `oldString.split(']')` but it does not return the array in the shape I was expecting.

Comment: why don't you split at every space ?

Comment: @rabsom that's a good point, let me update the question.

Comment: what did you try? and what goes wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could match the parts with the left and right delimiter.

```js
let string = '[foo bar] [faaaa] [feee] [fu]',
    array = string.match(/\[[^\]]+\]/g);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer below.

```js
let oldString = '[foo faa] [faaaa] [feee foo] [fu]';
let newStringArr = oldString.split(" ").join(',').replace(/\],\[/gi, "],d[").split(",d")
console.log(newStringArr);

document.write(JSON.stringify(newStringArr))
```