# Split a string at every occurrence of a date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to split a string at every occurrence of a specific pattern.
I have a string like this one:

```
91.240.109.42FrancePrestashop PI block
2021-06-02213.186.52.66FrancePrestaShop
2012-06-29
```

And I want to split the string at every occurrence of the date format `yyyy-mm-dd` mantaining the date in the splitted array, so the result I want to obtain is this one:

```
[91.240.109.42FrancePrestashop PI block 2021-06-02,213.186.52.66FrancePrestaShop 2012-06-29]
```

I have tried to split based on the date format but it does not work:

```
var splitted_string= result.split(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/)
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `^` and `$` anchors unless you're trying to match the entire string. Second, you probably should use a Lookahead if you want to keep the delimiter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: Isn't the expected result `["91.240.109.42FrancePrestashop PI block 2021-06-02",
  "213.186.52.66FrancePrestaShop 2012-06-29"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` here, with the following regex pattern:

```regex
[\s\S]+?(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$)
```

This will match all content up until the first date, repeteadly through the text.

```js
var input = `91.240.109.42FrancePrestashop PI block
2021-06-02213.186.52.66FrancePrestaShop
2012-06-29`
var matches = input.match(/[\s\S]+?(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Note that I use logic such that should the input not end in a date, the final split value would still be included.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const text = `91.240.109.42FrancePrestashop PI block
2021-06-02213.186.52.66FrancePrestaShop
2012-06-29`;
console.log( text.split(/(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/).map(x=>x.replaceAll("\n"," ")) )
```

The `(?<=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` pattern is a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with four digits, `-`, two digits, `-` and two digits.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bq0Xl7/2).

With `.map(x=>x.replaceAll("\n"," ")`, you replace each LF Char with a space.