# How to split one string including it in the array javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have the following strings:

```
const str1 = 'aabbcc';
const str2 = 'aabbccaaddaaaaeeff';
```

I need to split them in order to obtain the following result:

```
mySplitFunction(str1, 'aa')//<--- ['aa','bbcc']
mySplitFunction(str1, 'bb')//<--- ['aa','bb', 'cc']
mySplitFunction(str2, 'aa')//<--- ['aa','bbcc', 'aa','dd', 'aa','aa', 'eeff']
mySplitFunction(str2, 'dd')//<--- ['aabbccaa','dd', 'aaaaeeff']
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Consider this answer: [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001953/javascript-and-regex-split-string-and-keep-the-separator)

Comment: `const mySplitFunction = (str, splitter) => str.split(new RegExp(\`(${escapeForRegExp(splitter)})\`).filter(s => s)`

Comment: GG for the ones that thought I was asking for a simple split

Comment: you do, at least given your examples, which is all we got.

Comment: No bro I wanted to keep the delimiter inside. Thank you btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the separator in parenteses and filter the result to omit empty strings.

```js
const
    split = (string, separator) => string
        .split(new RegExp(`(${separator})`))
        .filter(Boolean),
    str1 = 'aabbcc',
    str2 = 'aabbccaaddaaaaeeff';

console.log(...split(str1, 'aa')); // ['aa','bbcc']
console.log(...split(str1, 'bb')); // ['aa','bb', 'cc']
console.log(...split(str2, 'aa')); // ['aa','bbcc', 'aa','dd', 'aa','aa', 'eeff']
console.log(...split(str2, 'dd')); // ['aabbccaa','dd', 'aaaaeeff']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```js
const str1 = 'aabbcc';
const str2 = 'aabbccaaddaaaaeeff';
function mySplitFunction(str, delimiter){
  return str.split(new RegExp(`(${delimiter})`)).filter(s => s)
}

console.log(mySplitFunction(str1, 'aa'))
console.log(mySplitFunction(str1, 'bb'))
console.log(mySplitFunction(str2, 'aa'))
console.log(mySplitFunction(str2, 'dd'))
```