# Javascript split sentence from special character

Tags: javascript

i need to separate the special character【０００３】from the text 一方、テオフィリ

```
<div class="PAR">
        【０００３】一方、テオフィリン系薬剤においては、安全域が狭く使用面の制約を
 </div> 

if(dataText.match(/【[０１２３４５６７８９]+】/)){

            let textSplit = dataText.split(/【[０１２３４５６７８９]】/);

            console.log("find text ", textSplit);
          }
```

The output need to be an array with [ 【０００３】, 一方、テオフィリ ];

The problem it is on the split

Comment: Assuming there will only be one `】`, you can split on that using something like this: [Javascript and regex: split string and keep the separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221523/1650337)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method directly:

```
const str = '０００３】一方、テオフィリン系薬剤においては、安全域が狭く使用面の制約を';

const words = str.split('】');
console.log(words[0]);
console.log(words[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check "splitting and keeping the separators".  https://www.wisdomgeek.com/development/web-development/javascript/javascript-split-string-and-keep-the-separators/

```js
const re = /(【[０１２３４５６７８９]+】)/;
const s = "【０００３】一方、テオフィリン系薬剤においては、安全域が狭く使用面の制約を";
const out = s.split(re);
console.log(out);
```