# How can I split a string into words with JavaScript starting at a particular character, and then end at the next space?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I'd have a string that is something along the lines of:

`"This is a string. $This is a word that has to be split. There could be $more than one in a string."`

And I want to split it into an array so it ends up like this:

`["This is a string. ", "$This", " is a word that has to be split. There could be ", "$more", " than one in a string."]`

So basically, I need to have them split on '$' until just before the next space. I would also like to keep the spaces in the other strings if possible. Is there a way to do this with `split()` or would regex need to be used here?

Comment: for more detail about the answer, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25221523/12743243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split on `\$[^ ]+` which matches a `$` sign followed by some number of non-space characters. By putting the regex into a capturing group we ensure the split strings also end up in the output array:

```js
const str = "This is a string. $This is a word that has to be split. There could be $more than one in a string."

console.log(str.split(/(\$[^ ]+)/))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern `\B\$\w+` should do the trick for you.

```js
const str = "This is a string. $This is a word that has to be split. There could be $more than one in a string.";

console.log(str.split(/(\B\$\w+)/g));
```